# Can I play my PSOne games (previously bought for PS3) on PS Vita ?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps-vita, ps1

I know that exists a retrocompatiblity, but those PSOne games I've own, were bought before PS Vita being released.

Comment: do you own the stuff? try it out! and tell us

Comment: I'm going to buy the Ps Vita yet! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the game is available for the Vita then it should be fine.  I purchased Final Fantasy VII as a ps1 classic before the vita, and I'm able to play it on the vita.  The thing is not all ps1 classics are one the vita, but most of them are, so if the classic you want to play includes the vita you can play it, even if it was purchased before the vita existed.